# Mult Mapping Dapper

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, dapper

Estou tendo problemas com o Mult Mapping do dapper, quando tento executar a query a seguir não está mapeando os ids dos objetos o select é este:

```
var sql = @" SELECT 
                    ofi.id_oficina,
                    ofi.codigo,
                    p.id_pedido, 
                    p.data_atuacao_oficina ,
                    p.numero, 
                    s.id_sinistro,
                    s.codigo,
                    v.id_veiculo,
                    v.placa, 
                    v.modelo, 
                    v.tipo ,
                    m.id_marca,
                    m.nome
                FROM 
                    pecas.oficinas ofi
                    INNER JOIN pecas.pedidos p
                        ON p.cod_oficina = ofi.id_oficina
                    INNER JOIN pecas.sinistros s
                        ON s.id_sinistro = p.cod_sinistro
                    INNER JOIN pecas.veiculos v
                        ON v.id_veiculo = p.cod_veiculo
                    INNER JOIN pecas.marcas m
                        ON m.id_marca = v.cod_marca
                    INNER JOIN pecas.clientes c
                        ON c.id_cliente = s.cod_cliente
                    INNER JOIN pecas.itenspedido ip
                        ON ip.cod_pedido = p.id_pedido
                        AND ip.autorizacao_cod_itempedido_fornecedor IS NOT NULL
                    INNER JOIN pecas.itenspedido_fornecedores ipf
                        ON ipf.id_itempedido_fornecedor = ip.autorizacao_cod_itempedido_fornecedor
                        AND ipf.devol_data_autorizacao IS NULL
                        AND ipf.data_prazo_entrega IS NOT NULL
                    INNER JOIN pecas.pedidos_fornecedores pf 
                        ON pf.cod_pedido = p.id_pedido
                        AND pf.data_autorizacao IS NOT NULL
                    LEFT JOIN conciliacao.conciliacoes conc 
                        ON conc.id_conciliacao = pf.cod_conciliacao
                WHERE 
                    (p.logistica_data_encerramento IS NULL OR p.logistica_data_encerramento >= current_date-60)
                    AND s.cod_cliente = @idCliente
                    AND p.cancelado IS NOT TRUE
                    AND ofi.email IS NOT NULL
                    AND (v.placa ILIKE @placa OR s.codigo ILIKE @sinistro)";

            var pedidos = Conn.Query<Oficina, Pedido, Sinistro, Veiculo, Marca, Pedido>
            (sql, (oficina, pedido, sin, veiculo, marca) =>
                {
                    pedido.Sinistro = sin;
                    veiculo.Marca = marca;
                    pedido.Veiculo = veiculo;
                    pedido.Oficina = oficina;


                    return pedido;
                },
            new
            {
                idCliente = codCliente,
                placa = string.IsNullOrEmpty(placa) ? "" : placa,
                sinistro = string.IsNullOrEmpty(sinistro) ? "" : sinistro
            }, splitOn: "id_pedido,id_sinistro,id_veiculo,id_marca")
```

Ja tentei fazer selecionando todos campos `ofi.*,p.*,s.*,v.*,m.*` e com os campos que vou precisar (prefiro fazer o select apenas com os campos que vou usar)

Obviamente preciso dos Ids para saber quem é quem, quando seleciono o objeto por ID ele mapeia corretamente (não é o automapper)

EDIT: Minha pergunta foi marcada como duplicada porem eu não tenho nenhum erro estourando, a query me retorna resultados porem os resultados não são preenchidos na lista de objetos.

Segue 2 prints do erro

[image: IdOficina não carregado]
[image: IdOficina não carregado]

Comment: Poste a sua entidade. Adicionalmente, tente adicionar um alias na consulta com o mesmo nome do ID, exemplo: **SELECT ofi.id_oficina as IdOficina**.

Comment: Funcionou colocando alias se quiser colocar como uma resposta^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que o nome do Campo no banco de dados (seu select) é diferente do nome de sua Entidade.

Basta alterar para ser iguais que tudo será resolvido. Uma opção simples é utilizar **Alias** em sua consulta, por exemplo:

```
SELECT
       ofi.id_oficina as IdOficina,
```

Outra opção seria mapemar manualmente o objeto dinâmico da consulta com os dados específicos, como por exemplo:

```
var sql = @"select top 1 person_id, first_name, last_name from Person";
using (var conn = ConnectionFactory.GetConnection())
{
    var person = conn.Query<Person>(sql)
                     .Select(item => new Person()
                     {
                       PersonId = item.person_id,
                       FirstName = item.first_name,
                       LastName = item.last_name
                     }
                     .ToList();

    return person;
}
```

Note que estou falando *explicitamente* que **PersonId = item.person_id**.

Alguns outros detalhes, inclusive como utilizar o `ColumnAttribute`, você pode verificar nas respostas [desta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8902674/4843158).